# How to run an event if a user is removed from a role?

Tags: discord.js

How can I run an event if the user is removed from a role?

I have tried `guildMemberUpdate` but I don't know how to use it.

```js
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', ( oldmember, newmember) => { 
    if(newmember.roles.find(j => j.id === "505763004797812766")){
      message.channel.overwritePermissions(message.author, {SEND_MESSAGES: true}); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  if (oldMember.roles.size > newMember.roles.size) {
    // code
  }
});
```